# How to ensure matched quotations in JSON using Python?

Tags: python, json, regex, parsing

I'm parsing through a text a sometimes I get the following

```
{"name":"John","last" : Doe", "Food":"Fries","Coffee" : "Need}
```

I'm dealing with someone else's data here so I just have to deal with it.

Is there a possible use of regex expressions (or anything else for that matter) Where I can read through the file and whenever I find unmatched quotations modify the file by matching them.

So I can end up with

```
{"name":"John","last" : "Doe", "Food":"Fries","Coffee" : "Need"}
```

Comment: is the unmatched quote always the last thing before a closing bracket?

Comment: @MoxieBall Nope Doe" also has. I presume it can be anywhere

Comment: @MoxieBall It can be anywhere

Comment: Do your real-life strings contain only letters, or at least not contain any characters with special meaning to JSON like `[]{}"\:,`?

Comment: What you're asking for is basically impossible in general, because it's ambiguous—but it may be possible, or even dead easy, for your particular data set. For example, if none of those special characters ever appear in your JSON strings, you know that an unclosed quote was supposed to end at the next one of `,:]}`, and an opened quote is only a little more complicated. But if you have to handle strings like `"spam:\"eggs\"}"` that may be missing quotes, that's a different story.

Comment: @mad_ yeah I didn't even catch that, whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If missing quotation marks are the only problem with the text **and** there are no escaped quotation marks within the fields, then you can repair the text by looking for the four types of irregularities.

```
s = '{name":"John","last" : Doe", "Food:"Fries","Coffee" : "Need}'
```

A missing quotation mark after a semicolon:

```
s = re.sub('"\s*:\s*(?=[^\s"])', '":"', s)
```

A missing quotation mark before a semicolon:

```
s = re.sub('(?<=[^\s"])\s*:\s*"', '":"', s)
```

A missing quotation mark before the closing brace:

```
s = re.sub('(?<=[^\s"])\s*\}', '"}', s)
```

A missing quotation mark after the opening brace:

```
s = re.sub('\{\s*(?=[^\s"])', '{"', s)
```

Apply all four transformations one after another, and hopefully the problem is gone:

```
print(s)
#{"name":"John","last":"Doe", "Food":"Fries","Coffee" : "Need"}
```